# Samsung galaxy gt-19070, wiped system in twrp

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung, twrp

I use Samsung galaxy gt-19070 that runs under cyanogenmod with rooted and bootloader unlocked. I recently wiped my system in twrp and my phone is stuck in "android is starting". Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only said that your "/system" partition is wiped so it means that only your "/system" partition is clean and other partitions are untouched. You also said you used TWRP. So, I assume you still have access to TWRP.

What you would need is:

- TWRP access
- Your original CyanogenMod Custom ROM zip file

Since you didn't state your TWRP Recovery version, I assume you are using version 2.x

Step 1:

(Skip this step if you still have your CyanogenMod ROM zip file)

Download your CyanogenMod ROM zip from where you originally downloaded it.

Step 2:

Boot into TWRP Recovery

Step 3:

Still in TWRP, go to "Mount" and tick the box with "Internal Storage" and "External Storage"

Step 4:

Go to "Install" and find the CyanogenMod ROM zip file that you originally flashed.

Note: the folder "sdcard" is your "Internal Storage" while the folder "sdcard1" is your "External Storage" or "SD Card"

Step 5:

After the flashing is completed, go to "Advanced" --> "Reboot" to reboot your phone

Your phone should now work normally as usual and CyanogenMod will load as per normal!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to install another custom rom for my phone. The twrp version is 3.0.2-0. Now with this (previous) condition I tried to flash a custom rom but it said no md5 file found and there was error installing zip file. Please help. Can I install another custom rom for my phone after wiping all my data and do I need to install the kernel too?

Comment: Thankyou. I was just able to flash the same custom rom (cyanogenmod) which I was using previously. Now its working perfectly better.